# add a css class to the body when a click happens

Tags: css, angularjs

Am struggling with AngularJS, any help would be appreciated. The issue is- I have a button at a div which when clicked should add a css class to the whole body of the app. Is it possible? Googling around suggested we could add the css class to the element in question.

To elaborate:

I have a main page that displays a form. It has a list of icons which when clicked should bring up a page showing details on the item and it should shift my main page to the left to make room for the details page.

```
    <ul data-ng-controller="myctrl">
       <li data-ng-click="showMe(0)">Item 1</li>
       <li data-ng-click="showMe(1)">Item 2</li>
       <span data-ng-include="template.url"></span>
   </ul>

   var myapp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
   myapp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope','$element',function($scope,$element){
       $scope.templates = [ {name: "item1", url: "item1.html"},
                            {name: "item2", url: "item2.html"}];
       $scope.showMe = function(index) {
          $scope.template = $scope.templates[index];
          $element('body').addClass("shiftToLeft"); //does not seem to have an effect!
       }
   }]);
```

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Why don't you just use normal jQuery for this?

Comment: So you think we can just guess your exact code? You need to show us some code otherwise we cant help. I can go Google an example if you really want... but I'm pretty sure you can do that yourself.

Comment: Pardon me for not being very clear. My mind's getting clouded :(. Have updated the question, hope it helps me get through the problem i have at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a directives for accomplishing CSS styling conditionally or dynamically:

for eg:

The `ngStyle` directive allows you to set CSS style on an HTML element conditionally.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle

Use `ng-class` to alter the class of the BODY tag on the fly
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did is adding on the body a directive `ng-class="currentPageName"` and I change this variable using the rootsScope : `$rootScope.currentPageName = "name_of_the_class"`.

So you need to change it for each of your controllers.